# How to make a cropped image fill all the View with flexbox and React-Native?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I want to make a cropedd image to fill all the view in my app.

My Code now is right this:

[image]

But I wanted that this small square with Homer eating this donuts fill all the screen, like this simulation I did:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class CroppedImage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.cropped}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png'
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const OFFSET_LEFT = 0;
const OFFSET_TOP = 0;
const IMAGE_WIDTH = 239 * 1.5;
const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 391 * 1.5;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#6699CC'
  },

  bg: {
    opacity: 0.25,
    width: IMAGE_WIDTH,
    height: IMAGE_HEIGHT
  },

  image: {
    marginLeft: -OFFSET_LEFT,
    marginTop: -OFFSET_TOP,
    width: IMAGE_WIDTH,
    height: IMAGE_HEIGHT
  },

  cropped: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'absolute'
  }
});
```

Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the property resizeMode to the Image as follows :

```
 <Image
    style={styles.image}
    source={{
    uri:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png'
    }}
    resizeMode:'contain'
 />
```

and let me know if it worked or not!

Comment: It doesnt compile Lahkin. I think that resizeMode its not a props from Image

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the resizeMode to the style like so:

```
image: {
    marginLeft: -OFFSET_LEFT,
    marginTop: -OFFSET_TOP,
    width: IMAGE_WIDTH,
    height: IMAGE_HEIGHT,
    resizeMode: "contain"
  },
```

You can read more on it in the documentation here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode